# Reverse Engineering SNES adapter

Tags: firmware, hardware, firmware-analysis, game-hacking, api-reversing

A good "Hello world" for everybody here

I've bought a [Mayflash PC052 adapter](https://www.mayflash.com/Up/day_120604/201206041208216074.jpg) to convert an original SNES-mini controller ([CLV-202](https://cdn02.nintendo-europe.com/media/download_import/img-clv2-controller-640x430.png)) to a USB port on PC or PS4...
The thing is, this CLV-202 controller isn't working with the adapter, I've asked for a firmware update to Mayflash, and it seems they are not interested to update it.
I've spent a lot of money in both devices and I want to try to mod the firmware to make the controller work.
I've tested my CLV-202 in a Nintendo Wii, and its working flawless. This adapter (PC052) was made to work with a Wii classic controller ([RVL-005](https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_NQ_NP_2X_883040-MLB32327367646_092019-F.webp)), if you saw both pictures, you will notice that CLV-202 and RVL-005 looks very similar, mine have less 5 buttons to me to care about
*** End of my sad history ***

So, I must start from where?
How to create a "dump" file of this firmware to my PC? Is it possible to edit it (w/o the source code)?
I'm a 101% noob in this area, and have 0% idea in how to start... but I want to learn with you all

PS: I don't care if the "original intended" devices stop working after the mod, just want this CLV-202 controller working